# Continuity of a function with respect to various topologies (example)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $$f(x)= \begin{cases}
-x-1, &\text{if }x≥0\\
1, &\text{if }x<0.
\end{cases}$$

Denote by

- $U$ the *usual* topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
- $H$ the *half-open interval* topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
- $C$ is the *open half-line topology* on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is $f$:

1. $U$-$U$ continuous?
2. $U$-$H$ continuous?
3. $U$-$C$ continuous?
4. $H$-$U$ continuous?
5. $C$-$C$ continuous?
6. $C$-$U$ continuous?
7. $C$-$H$ continuous?
8. $H$-$H$ continuous?

So, I kinda understand how to find things that are $U$-$U$ or whatever continuous, but the function is kinda throwing me off. So maybe some tips or suggestions as to where to start.

Answer (score 1):

We should start by looking at what the inverse images of various basic open sets look like.  This will help us determine the continuity of the function. (And plotting the graph of the function is quite helpful.)

Let's start out with $U$, the usual topology.  The basic open sets in this topology are just the open intervals $(a,b)$ for $a<b$.  The inverse image of these sets break down into several cases.

- If $a < b \leq -1$, then $f^{-1} [ (a,b) ] = ( -b-1 , -a-1 )$;
- If $a < -1 < b \leq 1$, then $f^{-1} [ (a,b) ] = [ 0 , -a-1 )$;
- If $a < -1 < 1 < b$, then $f^{-1} [ (a,b) ] = [ 0 , -a-1 ) \cup ( -\infty , 0 )$;
- If $-1 \leq a < b \leq 1$, then $f^{-1} [ (a,b) ] = \varnothing$;
- If $-1 \leq a < 1 < b$, then $f^{-1} [ (a,b) ] = ( -\infty , 0 )$;
- If $1 \leq a < b$, then $f^{-1} [ (a,b) ] = \varnothing$.

As $[ 0 , 1 ) = [ 0 , -(-2)-1 ) = f^{-1} [ (-2,1) ]$ is not open with respect to the usual topology, then $f$ is not $U$-$U$ continuous.  A simple check shows that all of these sets are open in the half-open interval topology, and so $f$ is $H$-$U$ continuous. As $(-4,-2) = ( -3-1 , -1-1 ) = f^{-1} [ (1,3) ]$ is not open in the open half-line topology, then $f$ is not $C$-$U$ continuous

For the half-open interval topology you perform a similar analysis for the basic open sets of this topology, which are of the form $[ a , b )$ for $a < b$.  (If you know the connection between this topology and the usual topology, you should be able to see that the above actually answers the question of the possible $U$-$H$, $H$-$H$ and $C$-$H$ continuity of $f$ for ***two*** of these.)

Finally for the half open-line topology you consider the inverse images of all sets of the form $( a , + \infty )$.

Comment: Should your first thing when discussing usual topologies.  Should $H-U$ be $U-H$ and $C-U$ be $U-C$?   So for the $H-U$, $H-H$, $C-H$ part is this correct?  It is $H-U$ continuous.  It is not $C-H$ continuous because [0,1) is not C-open.  Then it is $H-H$ open.  Then for the half open-open line topologies.  It is not C-C continuous because $f^(-1)(a,+ \infty)$ where $a<-1$ is not going to be C-open.  Similarly, it will not be C-U.

Comment: @Randomstop: When you said $H$-$U$ continuous, I imagined this meaning that the function is continuous from $\mathbb{R}$ with the $H$ topology to $\mathbb{R}$ with the $U$ topology (the _domain_ has the $H$ topology, and the _range_ has the $U$ topology).  Was this interpretation incorrect?

Comment: yup thats right :/  Im just a bit confused still then :/

Comment: @Randomstop: It's just notation, but now we _know_ that we are using the notation in the same way.  If we give the _range_ the $H$ topology, consider the inverse image of (the $H$ open set) $[ -2,0 )$.  In which topologies is this set open?  I'm pretty sure that you've handled the cases where you give the _range_ the $C$ topology correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a breakdown of my attempt for each one of my questions:

1. U-U Continuous:  $(-2,1)$ is open in the U topology. $f^{-1}((-2,1))=[0,1)$.  $[0,1)$ is not open in the U topology and therefore f is not U-U continuous.
2. U-H Continuous:  $(-2,1)$ is also H-open, which implies that f is not U-H continuous.
3. U-C Continuous:  Yes, it is U-C continuous.  Why not sure...
4. C-C Continuous:  The function $f^{-1}((a,+ \infty))= [0,a-1)$ where $a\lt-1$.  Which is not C-open and therefore not C-C continuous.
5. H-U Continuous:  [-3,1) is open in the H topology.  $f^{-1}([-3,1)=[0,2]$.  [0,2] is not H-open and therefore it is not H-U continuos.
6. C-U Continuos:  No, [0,1) is not C-open and therefore it is not C-U continuous or C-H continuous.
7. C-H Continuous:  No, See #4.
8. H-H Continuous:  No, similar to #5.

I am really not sure if this is correct and would really appreciate corrections or feedback!

Comment: The first two are fine. $f$ is not $U$-$C$ continuous: look at the inverse image of $(0,\to)$. If $a<-1$, $f^{-1}[(a,\to)]=(\leftarrow,a)$, not $[0,a)$; however, this also is not $C$-open, so $f$ is indeed not $C$-$C$ continuous, and this example will also still work for $(7)$. In $(5)$ you want to look at the inverse image of a $U$-open set, not an $H$-open set, so this doesn’t work; it does work for $(8)$, however. I’m not sure *what* you were thinking in $(6)$.