# Topology - Connected Images

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a topological space and let Y = {0,1,2} have the D topology.  Assume f: X$\rightarrow$Y is a continuous function.  If A is a connected subset of X, what are the possible values of the image f(A)?  Explain.

From my understanding the image f(A) has to equal 0,1, or 2 because it is connected and therefore, the only continuous functions from X to {0,1,2} are the constant functions?

Comment: That’s correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Wow im getting good at this!  Thanks so much!  Also would you be willing to look at this problem for me: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602353/continuity-of-a-function-with-respect-to-various-topologies-example